# Course Scheduling with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm working on a scheduling project for a school that assign courses to available classrooms. I have tree tables like these (simplified):

TCourse: CourseID, CourseCode, Hours, Capacity, ScheduleID ...

TClassroom: ClassroomID, ClassroomName, Quota ...

TCourseClassroom: CourseClassroomID, CourseID, ClassroomID, StartHour, FinishHour, ScheduleID

Hours between 08:00-20:00

Below code get courses one by one and assign them classrooms that have closest capacity then update classroom to sign that classroom is used. (Code translated to English for your reading and understanding)

```
    public ActionResult Schedule()
    {
        int[] hours = { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };

        using (ApsContext db = new ApsContext())
        {
            List<TCourse> courses = new List<TCourse>();
            List<TClasssroom> clasRooms = new List<TClasssroom>();
            int lastScheduleId = 0;

            courses = db.TCourse.OrderBy(x => x.Quota).ToList();

            foreach (var itemCourse in courses)
            {
                var clasRoom = db.Classroom.Where(x => x.PlanID == lastScheduleId && x.Capacity >= itemCourse.Quota).OrderBy(x => x.Capacity).FirstOrDefault();

                if (classRoom != null)
                {
                    var courseId = itemCourse.CourseID;
                    var classRoomId = clasRoom.ClassroomID;
                    var scheduleId = itemCourse.ScheduleID + 1;

                    db.Entry(classRoom).Entity.ScheduleID = scheduleId;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    CourseClassroom newCourseClassroom = new CourseClassroom();
                    newCourseClassroom.CourseID = courseId;
                    newCourseClassroom.ClasssroomID = classRoomId;
                    newCourseClassroom.ScheduleID = scheduleId;

                    db.TCourseClassroom.Add(newCourseClassroom);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Schedule");
        }
    }
```

This code use a class just one time but in a day that classroom has 12 hours. Think about all courses are 2 hour. So i need to use that classroom 6 times in a day. I can't imagine best way for this purpose. I think to update database that classroom is used with hours or should i do it in just code? Any idea will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, but maybe is not the fastest one.

1. Remove the `.FirstOrDefault();` sentence, so in `var classRoom` you have a Enumerable with all the classes big enought for the course.
2. Foreach classroom, find in the `TCourseClassroom` all the CourseClassroom that contains this classroom and order them with the EndHour.
3. Check if you course Hour plus the EndHour of the CourseClassroom is less than 20, and if it is, you can put your course in this class.

public ActionResult Schedule() {

```
int[] hours = { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };

using (ApsContext db = new ApsContext())
{
    List<TCourse> courses = new List<TCourse>();
    List<TClasssroom> clasRooms = new List<TClasssroom>();
    int lastScheduleId = 0;

    courses = db.TCourse.OrderBy(x => x.Quota).ToList();

    foreach (var itemCourse in courses)
    {
        var classRoomList = db.Classroom.Where(x => x.PlanID == lastScheduleId && x.Capacity >= itemCourse.Quota).OrderBy(x <= x.Capacity);

        TClasssroom availableClassRoom;

        foreach(TClasssroom classRoom in classRoomList)
        {
            TCourseClassroom courseClassroomList = db.TCourseClassroom.FindAll(x => x.ClassroomID == clasRoom.ClassroomID).OrderBy(x > x.EndHour).First();


            if(courseClassroomList == null)
            {
                availableClassRoom = classRoom;
            }
            else
            {
                if(courseClassroomList.EndHour + itemCourse.Hour <= 20)
                {
                    availableClassRoom = classRoom;
                }

            }   

        }
        if (availableClassRoom != null)
        {
            var courseId = itemCourse.CourseID;
            var classRoomId = clasRoom.ClassroomID;
            var scheduleId = itemCourse.ScheduleID + 1;

            db.Entry(classRoom).Entity.ScheduleID = scheduleId;
            db.SaveChanges();

            CourseClassroom newCourseClassroom = new CourseClassroom();
            newCourseClassroom.CourseID = courseId;
            newCourseClassroom.ClasssroomID = classRoomId;
            newCourseClassroom.ScheduleID = scheduleId;

            db.TCourseClassroom.Add(newCourseClassroom);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Schedule");
}
```

}

Comment: But there is no value in Start and EndHour yet. Need to update that values in foreach. Btw TCourseClassroom has no FindAll method. It's still helpful, thank you.

Comment: What about that: Put all classrooms to an array with a hour. So i will have 12 rows of that classroom than update TCourseClassroom table with these.

Comment: So the TCourse.Hours return the number of total hours of the course, and not the time? I can change the code with this new point of view.

Comment: Yes. It's total hour. When we put that course to a classroom i will update start and end times (for first course 08-10). Then another course will use that classroom with a time after last end time (10-12).

Comment: So then you can start filling a classroom with courses till it reach 22:00... I will update the code